# Gradle Zip task missing folders

Tags: gradle

When using following build file

```
dependencies {
    runtime libs.libName
}

task releaseZip(type: Zip) {
    baseName = 'fooBar'
    appendix = 'system'

    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'].each { folder ->
        from (folder) {
            into folder
        }
    }

    from configurations.runtime {
        into 'lib'
        include '*.jar'
    }
}
```

In this version only the 'lib' folder is present in the resulting zip file, without any of the other folders. In one of the interim versions of the build file, folders 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' were inside 'lib' folder instead of the root of the zip file.

How to make Gradle put folders 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' at the root of the zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'lib'` folder part of the task configuration is missing parentheses around the first argument of the method `from`:

```
from (configurations.runtime) {
    into 'lib'
    include '*.jar'
}
```

There are at least [two methods called `from` in the interface `CopySpec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#from-java.lang.Object...-). Probably, omitting the parentheses causes another method to be called, with some kind of expansion of `configurations.runtime`.